# Is there a way to remove data that is transferred to another tab? to avoid duplication in the same page? PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a quiz app, so the concept is when the quiz is submitted and is successfully scored then it will moved into the first tab which i've done successfully, but the problem is that the second tab, the quiz name that I've answered is still visible, how can I remove it or make it disappear after answering the exam.

So far, I've used this to remove, but the problem is only the first index is being remove from the second tab after I answered the activity.

[image]

First Tab - so this is the result of the exam

```
<?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
    <?php 
     $res = $result['activity'];  ?>
    
    <h4><?php echo $result['activity']; ?></h4>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is the Second Tab which shows all the Unanswered Exam

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <?php
        $pos = $post['activity'];  ?>
    <?php if($res != $post): ?>
    //So by comparing it if it is compared then the name must be removed
                        
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>activity/start/<?php echo $post['id']; ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>"> 
            <?php echo $post['activity']; ?> 
        </a>
                                        
                                                        
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ?>
```

Model for viewing all posted exams

```
public function class_posts($id){
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where('posts.teacher_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

Model for the result of the exam and viewing after the exam.

```
public function class_groups($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->join('results', 'results.post_id  = posts.id');
    $this->db->where('class_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('student_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->group_by('posts.activity');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

**var_dump($post)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looping through $results in your first tab code, you exit the loop with $res being assigned a value, this value does not change in your second tab code. That is why only one index is being excluded from the second tab. To fix this, compare $post to all the values stored in $results.

If your $results array contains all answered quizzes, you can check while looping through $posts if $results contains the value of $post using in_array. Here is a sample code:

```
if (!in_array($post, $results)) { //search in $results for $post
   // Show the Quiz since it has not been answered
}
```

I suggest creating a new array that holds every new value of $res in the first tab's loop and using the same logic above.

First Tab's new code

```
<?php $newArray = array();
      foreach($results as $result):
      $res = $result['activity'];
      array_push($newArray, $res) ?>
      <h4><?php echo $result['activity']; ?></h4>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Second Tab's new code

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): 
      $pos = $post['activity']; 
      if (!in_array($pos, $newArray)): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>activity/start/<?php echo $post['id'];?>/<?php echo $id;?>"> 
      <?php echo $post['activity']; ?> 
      </a>
      <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hello good sir, I understand your explanation and I tried your code and logic however after answering the exam It still give the same result which is shows the unanswered exam on the second tab.

Comment: Make sure that you replace $post with the activity name, and $results with an array that has all activities. Showing us a sample of what your arrays hold might help. I suggest creating a new array before first tab's loop, then after every new $res value, use array_push($newarray, $res). Finally look for $pos in $newarray using if (!in_array($pos, $newarray))

Comment: oh do you mean I will not remove the $post and $res that I've created?

Comment: - Please see the edited code above, and see the array of `$post`

Comment: but the `var_dump` of  `$results` is just `Array` can you help me with this sir?

Comment: That is because $results is Multidimensional, you need to look only for activities. Check the edited code above.